# How do I store the same types of classes that have a different generic inside of a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I've been tinkering with this and I have a 'RespawnManager' that I want to use to manage my multiple 'SpawnPoint' classes with different generics but it ended up forcing me to use generics for my 'RespawnManager' which I don't want.

Let's say I had a `SpawnPoint<T>` class and I made a `SpawnPoint<Enemy1>`, `SpawnPoint<Enemy2>`, and `SpawnPoint<Enemy3>`. Is there any way I can make a list that can just manage multiple 'SpawnPoint's of any generic?

Base class:

```
public abstract class SpawnPoint<T> : MonoBehaviour
{
    //how big the range of the spawn protection is   
    public int spawnProtectionRadius = 20;
    public bool Occupied { get; set; }

    public bool IsInSpawn(Transform target) 
    {
        Debug.Log((target.position - transform.position).magnitude);
        if ((target.position - transform.position).magnitude <= spawnProtectionRadius)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public abstract T Get();
}
```

Class that Inherits this

```
public class SeaMineSpawnPoint : SpawnPoint<Seamine>
{
    public override Seamine Get()
    {
        return SeaMineObjectPool.PoolInstance.Get();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        RespawnManager<Seamine>.respawnManager.AddSpawn(this);
    }
}
```

Respawn manager:

```
public class RespawnManager<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component
{

    public static RespawnManager<T> respawnManager;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<Transform> playerList;

    [SerializeField]
    private List<SpawnPoint<T>> spawnpoints;

    private float respawnCounter;

    private void Awake()
    {
        respawnManager = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (SpawnPoint<T> sp in spawnpoints)
        {
            Debug.Log(sp.transform.position);
        }
    }

    public void AddSpawn(SpawnPoint<T> spawnPoint)
    {
        spawnpoints.Add(spawnPoint);
    }

    public void RespawnSeaMines()
    {
        if (respawnCounter > 5)
        {
            respawnCounter = 0;
            foreach (SpawnPoint<T> sp in spawnpoints)
            {
                foreach (Transform playerT in playerList)
                {

                    if (sp.Occupied == false && !sp.IsInSpawn(playerT))
                    {
                        Component ourGameObj = sp.Get();
                        ourGameObj.transform.position = sp.transform.position;
                        ourGameObj.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                        sp.Occupied = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        respawnCounter += Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log(respawnCounter);
        RespawnSeaMines();
    }

}
```

ObjectPool

```
//Class that's used for object pooling of different types.
    //'T' must be a Unity component or it will error.
    public abstract class ObjectPool<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component
    {
        //An object with this specific component that we use to copy.
        [SerializeField]
        private T prefab;

        //Makes sure that only 1 coroutine runs at a time
        private bool coroutineIsRunning;


        //The singleton instance to our object pool.
        public static ObjectPool<T> PoolInstance { get; private set; }

        //A queue is used to organize plus activate and deactivate objects which
        //have this component.
        protected Queue<T> objects = new Queue<T>();

        private void Awake()
        {
            //Set the instance of this pool to this class instance. Only one of these can be set.
            if (PoolInstance != null)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Singleton already exists. Cannot make another copy of this");
            }
            PoolInstance = this;
        }


        public T Get()
        {
            //If the queue happens to be empty, then add a brand new component.
            if (objects.Count == 0) AddObjects(1);

            //Returns the generic component and removes it from the queue.
            return objects.Dequeue();
        }


        public void ReturnToPool(T objectToReturn)
        {
            //Disables the game object that the T component is attached to.
            objectToReturn.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            //Stores the T component in the queue.
            objects.Enqueue(objectToReturn);
        }

        public void AddObjects(int count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //Create a new copy of the prefab.
                //The prefab is a game object with the T component attached to it.
                T newObject = Instantiate(prefab);

                //Disable the game object.
                newObject.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                //Add the T component to the queue.
                //The T component is attached to the game object we created earlier.
                objects.Enqueue(newObject);
            }
        }

        public T GetWithDelay(int time)
        {
            T genericToReturn = null;
            if (!coroutineIsRunning)
            {
                coroutineIsRunning = true;
                StartCoroutine(GetCoroutine(time, genericToReturn));
            }
            return genericToReturn;
        }

        private IEnumerator GetCoroutine(int time, T generic)
        {
            float counter = 0;
            while (counter < time)
            {
                counter += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
            generic = Get();
            generic.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            coroutineIsRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you intend to use your different spawnpoints when iterating over the collection?

Comment: Each SpawnPoint references a certain object pool depending on the type. The RespawnManager checks if any of the SpawnPoints are "occupied" and then the first SpawnPoint that's vacant will be used to spawn the object associated with that SpawnPoint.

Comment: you should have a look at [covariant and contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces)

Comment: " will be used to spawn the object associated with that SpawnPoint" how is that achieved? by calling the Get method?

Comment: I edited my OP. Originally I didn't want to flood the post with all my code.

Comment: This seems wildly too complicated.  Wouldn't it just be a Transform?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to declare your `spawnpoints` property in `RespawnManager` as a `List<SpawnPoint<Component>>` instead of `List<SpawnPoint<T>>`. That will allow you to get rid of the `<T>` type parameter entirely from `RespawnManager` and make it non-generic.